# CSS Specificity - cross browser issues

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

This is a learning exercise for me, so thanks in advance for not telling me why I don't want to do to the following. I don't want to do, I want to understand.

Given the following CSS:

```
input[type="file"]:focus,
input[type="radio"]:focus,
input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

The specificity for both shows as 0,2,1, and everything I read about CSS says the second style should override the first as it comes last. If I get more specific about the second style, it wins. But as posted, Chrome doesn't display the outline, but IE11 and FF28 do. This seems to me to be such a fundamentally simple application of CSS. Does anyone have any insight into what the underlying issue is, so that I can pull it into my thinking as I'm developing stylesheets?

EDIT: Chrome also doesn't display the outline if I delete the second style. In Chrome, the outline: thin dotted are overridden by the following outline line. So it appears that per the spec, Chrome is playing by the book and FF and IE don't? Could it be a union vs. override difference in how browsers interpret CSS?

Comment: Could you provide a page we can visit to see the problem easily, please? (Specifically because if these are the only styles you’re applying, the OS stylesheet might apply something with the appearance of an outline.)

Comment: Please create a fiddle if possible jsfiddle.net. It would be easy to analyze and debug

Comment: It’s more complicated than a matter of specificity. If you use `outline: solid red 3px` in the second rule, it takes effect in FF, too. And even the code in the question has an effect in FF, but only partial: the top and left outline is solid, the other two are dotted. In IE, I cannot replicate the problem now; I thought it did, but now I can’t.

Comment: It works for me in IE11 and FF28. http://jsfiddle.net/Qpc88/

Answer (score 0):

With apologies, the error was mine. When I switched from bootstrap.min.css to bootstrap.less, I didn't remove the former from loading so it was loaded last and overrode my Site.less -> site.css. I figured it out after I tried to create a fiddle, which I should have done in the first place. Feel free to down-mod this post to hell in the way that it deserves.